# Exception while opening Netbeans

Tags: exception, netbeans, startup

While trying to open NetBeans 6.0 RC2 under JDK 1.6, the IDE not only it doesn't open but it throws this exception in the command line... I downloaded a JAR file that in theory has that LookupListener class but I don't know where to place it or if placing it somewhere will solve the problem.

Do you know why is that exception arising ?.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a release candidate of a really old version of Netbeans? Even if you needed a really old version you should probably  at-least get the stable final release.

Comment: Thankx you for answering... I will uninstall it and get the final release and see what happens... Cheera

Comment: Will. How are you ?... Thankx for your advice... I installed JSK 8 and the latest release of NB, and all worked fine... Thankx again...